# Cross platform environment paths

Tags: python, environment-variables, cross-platform

Let say I want to set environment variable from a python script. For example **PYTHONPATH**.

On Windows it will be `path1;path2;path3` (semicolon seperator).

On Linux it will be `path1:path2:path3` (colon seperator).

Is there a cross-platform way to build the path using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The os module has a variable for just this purpose:

```
path = os.pathsep.join(path_elements)
```

os.pathsep is ':' or ';' depending on where you are running.